# Custom Checkout with BigCommerce

Tags: nuxt.js, e-commerce, payment-gateway, bigcommerce, bigcommerce-checkout-sdk

i'm building a custom storefront with Nuxt 3 in SSR and using BigCommerce as e-commerce engine. I create a second channel for this and configured the domain. Via API I integrated almost everything, from product listing to the various operation for the cart. Now i want to implement the checkout, but i'm quite lost. My ideal scenario is to implement the checkout in my app, using the server to server API. I used the checkout API in order to create the order, but what about payments? Do I need to integrate each gateway separately and then tell BigCommerce that the payment is done, passing some values? I mean, the is no API endpoint that return the configured gateways in the Admin panel. So:

- What are the steps in order to build a complete custom checkout, expecially payment wise?
- If the effort is too high I can consider the redirect_url API from the cart. But i'd like the checkout to be at least in a custom subdomain such checkout.mydomain.com and not in the domain of bigcommerce, and more than that adding some style to the optimized checkout from bigcommerce.

Someone can point me in the right direction?